# [Koa]404 while passing throught the routeur

Tags: node.js, koa

I'm having some trouble with the Koa framework. I'm trying to build a pretty basic server by I'm having a problem with my router. The ctx always return 404 despite passing in my functions.

Some code :

```
//www.js
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();
const version = require('./routes/version');

app.listen(config.port, () => {
  console.log('Server is listenning on port ' + config.port);
});

app.use(version.routes());
app.use(ctx => {
    console.log ('test')
});


//version.js
const Router = require('koa-router');
const router = new Router();
router.prefix('/version');

router.use((ctx, next) => {
  ctx.vFactory = new VersionFactory(ctx.app.db);
  next();
});

router.get('/', getAllVersions);

async function getAllVersions(ctx, next) {
  const ret = await ctx.vFactory.getAllVersions();
  ctx.body = JSON.stringify(ret.recordset);
  console.log(ctx.body)
  await next();
}
```

I've checked a few threads. Most of the time, the problem seems to come from a non Promise based function in the await part of the router function. Here it is a simple DAO using mssql which is pretty promise based.

```
class DaoVersion {

    constructor(db) {
        this.pool = db;
    }
    async getAllVersions() {
        const me = this;
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          const ret= me.pool
          .query(getVersion);

          resolve(ret);
        });
    }
}
```

The console output seems good. I have my ctx.body set with my db data but if I try to check the whole context, I still have a 404. More interesting, if I try to ctx.res.write (using default node response) I got the "already end" message. So it seems Koa have sent the message before passing threw my function.

Any idea why and how I could correct that ?

Answer (score 1):

Koa default response.status code is 404, unlike node's res.statusCode which defaults to 200.

Koa changes the default status code to 200 - when your route set's a non empty value to ctx.body or in some cases you can manually change (like if you need to set it to 202) it by using ctx.status = xxx.

You can use this documentation for reference: https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/docs/api/response.md

Also, your route should be an async function:

```
router.get('/', async(ctx, next) => {

   ctx.body = await getAllVersions
   await next()
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know about the default 404.

I tried removing my DAO call and simply add an assignment to ctx.body and it works normally. As long as I add an async call, I got a 404. There must be something in my object Kao don't like.

I tried to move to express to test, worked first time. I'll try your way tomorrow, & see if that changes anything.

Comment: So, I tried by changing the way the function is called. Still the same problem. I think I'll stick with Express.